# Asp NET 5, Argument null Exception when using WebImage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a bit new in ASP Net 5. 
I am trying to use WebImage helper to Resize, Flip Vert/Horiz and save an image but everytime I use the WebImage helper I get an ArgumentNullException saying that HttpContext can't be null.

I understand that now there is a Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpContext instead, but does that mean that WebImage can't be used at all on ASP net 5 and/or Core as it demands a System.Web.HttpContext and not a Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpContext

I have something like:

```
WebImage photo = new WebImage(imagePath);
photo.FlipVertical();
photo.Save(imagePath);
```